# dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.*

Tags: java, android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhHhY.png)At the time of development,Application on the Android 5 system can be used normally,But in 5 the following system will Application no response .But I don't know what the reason is.The error log is as follows：

```
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.Application$OnProvideAssistDataListener', referenced from method .App.access$super 
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.Application$OnProvideAssistDataListener', referenced from method .App.access$super 
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.monkeyPatchExistingResources
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.pruneResourceCache 
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from .ui.module.main.SplashActivity.access$super 
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.zhengjin99.olivefortune.ui.module.main.SplashActivity.access$super 
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method .ui.module.main.SplashActivity.access$super 
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method .ui.module.main.SplashActivity.access$super 
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method .ui.module.main.SplashActivity.access$super 04-23 
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method .ui.module.main.SplashActivity.access$super 
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle',
CrashHandler.uncaughtException: Ohooo
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:packagename.ui.module.main.AssetAllocationFragment
```

Comment: There's no need to delete and repost your question if you make a mistake. There's an edit link below the tags under your question.

Comment: These are perfectly normal. They represent classes that are conditionally referred to from your code, but do not exist on the Android device or emulator, because they were introduced in newer versions of Android. `ArrayMap`, for example, was added in API Level 19 (Android 4.4). These messages do not represent a "collapse".

Comment: @CommonsWare so is that a problem for the device the app is running on?

Comment: @AkashAggarwal: As I noted, these are perfectly normal. The only place where there would be a problem is if you tried executing code that depended upon these missing classes or methods, and then you will get a regular Java stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for clearing it out

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem.Because of my fragment in the use of the latest API.
View.OnScrollChangeListener()-->API23.So the need to load the SDK version of the judgment.

Comment: You should mention, how you got to this solution so that others with the same error have a hint on how to tackle this issue.