# MySQL TIMESTAMP behaving weirdly

Tags: android, mysql, sql

In my chat application, I use `System.currentTimeMillis()/1000` on the android app to send the time the message was created at to my MySQL server, without the milliseconds part. Now the strange part is, my table has two records with the same value of milliseconds. Even stranger is that when I convert the milliseconds to readable time, the values are totally different!
Here is the output of two different queries:

```
SELECT max(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at)), created_at, message FROM messages WHERE mtype = 0 AND groups_id = 1;

 max(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at)) | created_at          | message |
+--------------------------------+---------------------+---------+
|                     1464096148 | 2016-04-25 13:57:18 | The   


SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at), created_at, MESSAGE FROM messages WHERE mtype = 0 AND groups_id = 1 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1;

 max(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at)) | created_at          | message |
+--------------------------------+---------------------+---------+
|                     1464096148 | 2016-05-24 18:52:28 | test
```

The output of the last query is what I remember sending from my client app.

Comment: I don't see any problem here, it should be different, you are selecting the max one in the first query, which probably belongs to `2016-05-24`

Comment: @sagi please see the value of milliseconds in the first column, they are totally same. And then check the 2nd column is totally different.

Comment: Why won't they? you have more then one record, so when you select `MAX()` it will select the maximum timestamp! The other columns without a group by clause and an aggregation function will be randomly picked

Comment: @sagi are you talking about the first query?

Comment: @sagi Nevermind my last comment, you're right. I wasn't aware about this behavior of SQL. Can you guide me to make that query right so it shows the right result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is acting weird, it acting exactly as it should be.

When you have more then one record, and you are using an aggregation function like `MAX()/MIN()/COUNT()...` , if the other columns without the aggregation function has different values, one of them will be picked(not sure by what order, I think randomly) .

So if you would like them to return the same thing, this is the query you should use:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at), created_at, message FROM messages 
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) =(SELECT  max(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at))
                                   FROM messages WHERE mtype = 0 AND groups_id = 1)
  and mtype = 0 AND groups_id = 1;
```

This will make sure to pick the record, where the timestamp equals to the maximum timestamp, this will make sure you pick the correct record. When dealing with aggregation functions, you have to specify to each column which one of the values you want.

Comment: Thankyou! I must be insane to try selecting things like this. The SQL query selecting the 2nd column randomly(probably) was what drove me crazy. Do you mind if I delete this question?

Comment: No problem, and nope, do what ever you'd like. @AkashAggarwal

Comment: I thought I was setting a bad example but a bad example is a good example too. I'd like to add for anyone reading this question that you don't need to call the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function in either side of `WHERE` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the answer-

> They represent classes that are conditionally referred to from your code, but do not exist on the Android device or emulator, because they were introduced in newer versions of Android. ArrayMap, for example, was added in API Level 19 (Android 4.4). These messages do not represent a "collapse".

Source:  [Comment on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812913/dalvikvm-could-not-find-class-android#comment62334975_36812913)